# Accessing a jQuery mobile clicked item

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I can't seem to understand how to get the actual link that was clicked. I'm trying my hand at making a widget. This is the code I used to actually execute a click:

```
$mID.find('a.next').on('click', function() {
    $mID.megamenu("nextMenu");
});
```

Where $mID is `$mID = $(":jqmData(role='megamenu')");`.

How could I access the clicked item from within the nextMenu function?

EDIT: I have a way of accomplishing this, but it's not ideal.

```
$mID.find('a.next').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('next');
    $mID.megamenu("nextMenu");
    $(this).removeClass('next');
});
```

And then, instead of trying to access $(this) within the nextMenu function, I can access $('.next') to isolate the specific instance. If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here.  Isn't the link the `this` inside of the callback function?

Comment: erm, $(this) will be $mID.find('a.next'). not $mID AFAIK. maybe i misunderstanded  the question

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding widgets, but that's how I thought to call a separate function. Basically, it backs out, then searches the entirety of the widgeted item, and it pulls all of the anchors, causing some grief. I have a somewhat hacky way of fixing it, but I'm open to alternatives. Check out my new code.